# can't get proper xpath Query for retrieving an image from a webpage

Tags: html, xml, xpath, yql

I'm creating a rss service using C# and one of the website that we retrieve rss news from it doesn't have direct link to its images but if we go to their directlink pages we can find a picture by the help of firebug and using "XPATH" feature in firebug I can get a XPATH query for that particular picture but it seems that xpathquery is not valid because I have checked its xpathquery with :
HtmlAgilityPack  and also yahoo YQL

here is the xpath that I retreive from firebug :

```
//body
  /form
   /table[2]
    /tbody
     /tr[2]
      /td
       /table
        /tbody
         /tr
          /td
           /table
            /tbody
             /tr
              /td
               /img
```

and here is my YQL

```
select * 
from html 
where url="http://isna.ir/ISNA/PicView.aspx?Pic=Pic-1718372-1&Lang=P" 
      and xpath='//body
                  /form
                   /table[2]
                    /tbody
                     /tr[2]
                      /td
                       /table
                        /tbody
                         /tr
                          /td
                           /table
                            /tbody
                             /tr
                              /td
                               /img'
```

this the website I want to retrieve images from it :

```
http://isna.ir/ISNA/PicView.aspx?Pic=Pic-1718372-1&Lang=P
```

since my Xpath ability is too weak and I know only few things about it I have to rely on tools such as firebug ... actually I know only firebug that return the xpath from selected html tag

so I have two question here :

1-would you please write me the correct xpath or advice me how to write a correct one?

2-is there any other tools such as firebug to showing the xpath corresponding of html tags?

regards.

Comment: @austin-powers: Because I feel *very sympathetic* to you, I am not answering your question. I urge you, instead, to start reading a good XPath book and to really learn XPath. You don't realize what you are missing. Also, grab my XPath Visualizer hosted at Lars Huttar's site (http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)  and play with it.

Comment: @austin-powers: This is a **FAQ: browser adds mandatory HTML elements to the DOM** like HEAD or TBODY. **Other DOM builder might not do such thing.**

Comment: @novatchev thanks for your advice but at least I know a little about xpath and thats why I've used HtmlAgilityPack  to convert a html to xhtml then get xpathQuery by the way your software doesn't help me to open that particular webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got my answer :
HtmlAgilityPack doesn't suppoer [tbody] and [html] tag inside xpathQuery so I've rewritten my query like :

```
//*[@id='Table2']/tbody/tr/td/table/tr/td/img
```

or

```
//body/form/table[2]/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/img
```

and here is what I've got from tracing HtmlAgilityPack

```
/html[1]/body[1]/table[2]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/img[1]
```

as all of above codes are correct for HtmlAgilityPack

and FYI there is another pluging for firebug called firepath which will give you concise query.

regards.